# Question on Helmholtz Equation in the senes of distributions

Tags: distribution-theory, greens-function

In the sense of distributions, the Green function of the Helmholtz equation
$$(\nabla^2+k^2)G(r)=\delta(r)$$
is an spherical wave
$$G(r)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\,.$$

How can I prove that a distribution like
$$G(x,y,z)=e^{ikz}\frac{e^{(ik/2z)[x^2+y^2]}}{z}\,,$$

which is is a wave with parabolic phase, 
does not equals a Dirac delta $\delta$ but correspond to a different distribution.